# ehcache.xml can't use the properties file property

Tags: java, xml, spring, ehcache

I define a system.properties in my class path, then I do like this in spring configuration xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/system.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

I aslo defind ehcache like this :

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />

    <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehCacheManager" />
    </bean>
```

I define a properties in system.properties file :

```
system.project_name=myproject
```

ehcache.xml like this :

```
<diskStore path="e:/${system.project_name}/cache" />
```

I want use the system.project_name property to store the cache, but when I deploy my project, I find the Directory is：

[image]

that is say I could't use the properties even I define a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring configuration xml file？

Comment: Is the `property-placeholder` defined in the same file as the `diskStore`?

Comment: property-placeholder define in applicationContext.xml in class path, ehcache.xml and applicationContext.xml in the same folder

Comment: I believe you have to define a `property-placeholder` per configuration file. Try it and let us know.

Comment: yes I have two spring configuration file, applicationContext.xml and applicationContext-mvc.xml，I have defined a property-placeholder in every configuration file, but it can't work