# MethodInvokingFactoryBean didn't work

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I create a properties file contain system properties in classpath, the name is system.properties

the file like :

```
system.project_name=springsilkworm
```

I also use EHcache, the ehcache.xml like:

```
<diskStore path="${java.io.tmpdir}/${system.project_name}/cache" />
```

I want use the system.project_name define in system.properties。

I developed my project based on Spring, so I created applicationContext.xml like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/system.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setProperty" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>system.project_name</value>
                <value>${system.project_name}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

but when I start my app， I find the folder which EHcahce use like :

[image]

that was say, the MethodInvokingFactoryBean didn't work, I also get the property in my code with System.getProperty("system.project_name") code，I got the result of “null”， why? I couldn't find out the wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ehcache.xml can't use the properties file property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190955/ehcache-xml-cant-use-the-properties-file-property)

Comment: yeah，they are same problem